# What the aria-busy and aria-tomic used for?

Tags: html

I could not find in which cases **Aria-atomic** and **aria-busy** attributes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A two second search on Google would have brought the following:

> aria-atomic: The aria-atomic=BOOLEAN is used to set whether or not the
>   screen reader should always present the live region as a whole, even
>   if only part of the region changes. The possible settings are: false
>   or true. The default setting is false.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions

> aria-busy="true" is set when a relevant portion of the page is
>   currently getting updated and the users are waiting to read the
>   updated content. Users of assistive technology will not be able to
>   read anything while the content is getting updated. They could
>   probably hear "busy" with some screen readers. Once the content is
>   updated, content authors can set aria-busy="false" or remove the
>   aria-busy attribute Once the content is updated, the assistive
>   technologies gather the updated information and provide it to the
>   user.

Source: https://accessibilityresources.org/aria-busy

Answer (score -1):

Aria, is a set of attributes that are added to HTML in order to make web apps more accessible to users with disabilities.

Aria-atomic, Aria-busy, and more, are just some attributes specific to live regions on the webpage.

check [this](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/states_and_properties#attrs_liveregions) for more info.